# Change value of a var in attached script when Instantiate C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't apply anything to this 'bullet' I instantiate, i can't access the scipts on it. After instatiate, I want the var in scriptbullter attached to it to take the value of 1.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton (1) && canFire) {

    var mousePosition = FindObjectOfType<Camera> ().ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Input.mousePosition.z - FindObjectOfType<Camera> ().transform.position.z));

    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, Mathf.Atan2 ((mousePosition.y - transform.position.y), (mousePosition.x - transform.position.x)) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90);

    bullet bulletobj = Instantiate (bulletFired, transform.position + transform.forward * 2, Quaternion.identity) as bullet;
    bulletobj.GetComponent<scriptbullet>().bulletDamages = 1; //this line doesn't work

    bulletobj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = (mousePosition - transform.position).normalized * bulletSpeed * Time.smoothDeltaTime;

    canFire = false;
}
```

Thanks in advance guys :D

Comment: Split the line up, which part fails, `bulletobj.GetComponent<scriptbullet>()`,  `GetComponent<scriptbullet>().bulletDamages`, or `bulletDamages = 1`. Depending on which it fails on it is a different problem.

Comment: The first one fails, it's a script attached to the bullet and not to the shooter which is the GameObject (the second one)...

Comment: How does it fail, please copy and paste the exact error text in to your question.

Comment: The error is 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object', but someone already took me to another thread that doesnt fix my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bulletobj.GetComponent<scriptbullet>()` is failing because `bulletobj` is null. The object returned from `Instantiate` is not a `bullet` but instead is a `GameObject`, change that line of code to

```
GameObject bulletobj = Instantiate (bulletFired, transform.position + transform.forward * 2, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

Comment: Oh I think it works now I'll see if the bullet took the var

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer if it solved your problem.